# GitHub SalesForce UI is not working

Tags: android, user-interface, github, salesforce

I am trying to develop a own customize sales force android App by the use sales force SDK ( forcedroid ) .

[image]

Here "SalesforceSDK" is in workspace and as well as  my android App is in workspace  "sfaAndroid". When I am running my App sfaAndroid is showing other UI .Why below UI is showing in my emulator i
   didn't get ?

[image]

My Manifest of sfaAndroid is as below

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.dmt.sfa"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0"
android:installLocation="internalOnly">

<application android:icon="@drawable/company_logo_1"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name=".sfaAndroidApp"
          android:manageSpaceActivity="com.salesforce.androidsdk.ui.ManageSpaceActivity">

    <!-- Launcher screen -->
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<!--
    GCM permission to ensure that only this application can
    receive the messages and registration result. This must be of
    the format <app-package-name>.C2D_MESSAGE for it to work.
-->
<permission android:name="com.dmt.sfa.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.dmt.sfa.C2D_MESSAGE" />
  </manifest>
```

As you can see my launching class is MainActivity and I am going to show UI of   MainActivity.java

```
     setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

main.xml is as follow

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="#454545"
android:id="@+id/root">

<include layout="@layout/header" />

<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button android:id="@+id/fetch_contacts" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:onClick="onFetchContactsClick"
          android:text="@string/fetch_contacts_button" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/fetch_accounts" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:onClick="onFetchAccountsClick"
          android:text="@string/fetch_accounts_button" />       

    <Button android:id="@+id/clear" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:onClick="onClearClick"
          android:text="@string/clear_button" />
    </LinearLayout>

   <ListView android:id="@+id/contacts_list" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
       </LinearLayout>
```

So just above Layout is not working or showing in my emulator . I did not get what's wrong is going on here ? If anyone have any clue please help me . Thanks in advance to all.

Comment: I face problem while Integrating with salesforce launching can you please expose your launching class MainActivity.java code so i can clear myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because, before showing particular app related page, you need to login into SalesForce so that you can get login credentials which are further used to do operations like fetching files from online account, creating contacts etc.

After successfull login only, you will be redirected to default page in your app.

**Edit :**

```
SalesforceSDKManager.initNative(getApplicationContext(), 
            new KeyImpl(), ActivityToGoAfterLogin.class);
```

As you can see in above code, we need to mention the Activity in `initNative` method. After successful login, user will be redirected to the mentioned Activity of your application.

Comment: Is there any way to change login design . I want to change our UI showing Some Other text in the place of "Salesforce".

Comment: I don't think so as SalesforceSDK is library and user is navigated to LoginActivity present in that library in which login page is displayed in a webview.